# Identify Row and Column of Specific Value in Dist Object

Tags: r

I have a dist class object returned by the stringdistmatrix function from the stringdist package. I want to identify the row and column of every entry in the object that is less than 10, for example. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this without converting the dist object to a matrix? Thanks.

Tom

Comment: `which(x <= 10, arr.ind=TRUE)` ? though if that works it may be coercing to matrix in the background.

Comment: Zheyuan, post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Zheyuan You might consider commenting to the OP there, who earlier left a comment saying they thought the answer might have a problem. I pinged them about accepting (assuming either of the answers actually works for them).